# MagickReadImage fails to read any image

Tags: c, imagemagick, windows-subsystem-for-linux, magickwand

I'm using ImageMagick to build a C application.
A sample code is:

```
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>
...
void * readPng(char *filename) {
    MagickWandGenesis();
    MagickWand * pngimgreader;
    pngimgreader = NewMagickWand();
    if (MagickReadImage(pngimgreader, "66666660_EAN-8.png")==MagickFalse) {
        int err = dump_error(pngimgreader);
        return -1;
    }
    return (void *)pngimgreader;
}
```

I'm always getting MagickFalse. I've tried with several images.
The dump_error call says:

> ERROR: unable to open image `66666660_EAN-8.png': No such file or
> directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874

or similar message for other images

I'm stuck on that error. Any help is welcome.

Command:
pkg-config --list-all | grep MagickWand
gives

```
Wand-6.Q16             MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
MagickWand-6.Q16       MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
Wand                   MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
GraphicsMagickWand     GraphicsMagickWand - GraphicsMagick Wand image processing library
Wand-im6               MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
MagickWand             MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
MagickWand-im6         MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
MagickWand-im6.q16     MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
```

Comment: Try a full, absolute filespec.

Answer (score 0):

It was an unexpected change in the working directory defined by my development environment.

Comment: The 'working directory' concept was designed for interactive, buman users.  Do not use it in code.

Comment: Windows has shell API calls to return useful folder specs.